# How to get image URI from the gallery using fragements

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi in the below code simple functionality I am imaplemeting one button named as pan_card.if user click on pan_card user can able to choose image from the gallery.After choose the image from I am using one textview to set the text.

But nothing happening
can any one help me where I did the mistake

```
    pan_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                // selectImage();
                                                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1000);
                                                notes_title = "PAN";
                                                pan = "1";
                                            }
                                        });
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Log.d("data", String.valueOf(data));
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1000) {
                Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                
                Log.d("imagepath", String.valueOf(returnUri));
                no_file_pan.setText("image");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: on what point nothing happening? After image selection? No image selection coming? No permission request commng?

Comment: @anatoli image selection is happening after that no_file_pan.setText("image"); not setting to the textviw

Comment: @blackapps no it is not executing

Comment: @blackapps added a log statement as first line not triggering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217078/discussion-between-jyothi-chandra-and-blackapps).

Comment: @blackapps updated my code please have a look

Comment: Where do your functions reside? In an activity or a fragment? Your problem is not getting an uri but an onActivityResult that is not called. Please adapt the subject.